# GAE minor major exception when deployed

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I'm trying to deploy a simple application to the GAE. Locally everything is running flawlessley using Java 7 and GAE 1.9.18. When deployed, I'm getting a Server Error and the [logs](http://pastebin.com/f1NCqVwQ) are showing an unsupported major minor version 52.

I tried compiling everything using Java 8, but this results in the same error. How should I continue solving this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GAE doesn't support Java 8 yet. Compile with Java 7.

Comment: I tried this already. Set my Project facet to Java 1.7 (http://imgur.com/38cMHLj)

Comment: I don't know which OS you're using but Java 8 is probably in your PATH variable. On Linux you can check `java -version` which version is the default one. Find on the web how to set the default Java on your OS, it will solve the problem.

Comment: The problem was indeed my OS(Debian) using Java8 as default. I was able to change this setting with the following command: 'sudo update-alternatives --config java'